# Is it okay to shorthand a function call using a macro? C++

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor

I am slowly writing an emulator for a gameboy using C++, I am currently working on the CPU side of things. I have written a generic function that takes any two registers of the CPU and returns as a Word data type. As it is necessary to access individual registers and also a combination of registers.

```
const Word get_word(Byte *registerOne, Byte *registerTwo)
{
    return ((*registerOne << 8) | *registerTwo);
};
```

calling this function gets tedious as you have to specify each register

`get_word(&this->registers.h, &this->registers.l)`

My question is if it okay to define a macro like so

```
#define get_HL() get_word(&this->registers.h, &this->registers.l)
```

since now I can call it using
`get_HL()`

The reason why I want to do it like this since I don't want to create more private/public functions that just perform function calls.

I have tried compiling and it seems to work as it should since its just a pre-processor macro but I am not sure of the design implication

EDIT:

Okay I mean there are glaring flaws with this and you should just make a function, just as much work to make a function or write a macro.

```cpp
const Word get_HL() { return this->get_word(&this->h, &this->l); };
```

Let this be a post for people who had the same idea and hopefully stop making the same mistake

Comment: `I don't want to create more private/public functions that just perform function calls.` Why not?

Answer (score 2):

No, this isn't OK in my opinion. It hides what arguments you're passing into the function, and macros don't respect scopes and as such are highly susceptible to name conflicts. This seems like an ideal use case for a non-static member function.

Comment: Alright thank you, shame the question is closed, I made functions in the end but it's important to ask what is good design and how to improve current design